# RegExp(/[a-z\d]/g).test('5') is returning true or false each time?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

*Why is this regex not working properly ?*

```
 new RegExp(/[a-z\d]/g).test('5');
```

*The result is sometimes true and other time false.
It keeps toggling between true/false*

```js
var regx = new RegExp(/[a-z\d]/g);

console.log(regx.test('5')) // true
console.log(regx.test('5')) // false
console.log(regx.test('5')) // true
console.log(regx.test('5')) // false
```

Comment: Sometimes I think Javascript was invented by Microsoft (But to be fair, they actually developed Typescript, which is great)

Comment: Regex is stateful with the `g` modifier

Comment: `match` is not stateful

Comment: @bm_i what is the use case of such behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the result is looking again, from the start:
*(the `lastIndex` property shows it: after first find `lastIndex`=== 1, but since string is has length 1, the next search/test is `false`, at the ende of the string it `lastIndex` is "reset" to 0)*

```js
var regx = new RegExp(/[a-z\d]/g);

console.log(regx.test('5'), regx.lastIndex) // true 1
console.log(regx.test('5'), regx.lastIndex) // false 0
console.log(regx.test('5'), regx.lastIndex) // true 1
console.log(regx.test('5'), regx.lastIndex) // false 0
```

Comment: what does `regx.lastIndex` mean?

Comment: @HiteshBhayani `regx.lastIndex` is the index of where to start next match. details can be found here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp